# Is it possible to get Node Id that paid an invoice?

Tags: lightning-network

I know it's possible to decode an invoice to see which node ID signed it by decoding it according to specs.

Is it possible to get Node ID **that paid an invoice to my node**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The buyer has privacy by default. The only information sent in a payment is the payment_hash, the amount and a CLTV value.

Comment: As Mark said do to the onion routing you will not know who paid the invoice. You know which Channel partner forwarded the payment to you. In theory you could ask them from which Chanel partner they received the payment and so on. But the protocol does not support this